# Google Scholar Search Engine (Crawl Bot) Copyright issue inquiry

Tags: copyright, google-scholar

I have a question about the Google Scholar Search Engine (Grawl Bot) copyright issue. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is the story. My university library accidentally uploaded my restricted report as an open-access document to the internet without my permission. After I found this, I notified my university, and it was removed from the university library website. But Google Grawl Bot is so powerful, and it captured that report, and it is available on Google Scholar now. If you click that report, you can see something like this: "This is the html version of the file https://***(my university)***. Google automatically generates html versions of documents as we crawl the web."

I just wonder do I have the right to notify Google to remove my report from Google Scholar after explaining what happened to Google? I checked online, and I found Google has a department called "Copyright removal" to handle those copyright issues.

Since this is a careless mistake of my university library, and my university library has removed my report. The only thing left is to ask Google to remove it from its own Google Scholar website.

Answer (score 3):

It is doable, but will take time (I managed to get a picture of my son removed that he found problematic when the girls in fifth grade thought it funny). First file through the Google copyright removal department. If they don't respond (but I hear they are getting better) you can threaten with a DMCA take-down notice, since you own copyright on the text. Even if you get it taken down, Google has lots of copies, so check back every now and then.

It is better for universities NOT to engage in restricted research, in my opinion. The results should be available for all, and free of charge. But that's my personal opinion.

Comment: It is just like accidentally uploading a thesis that is still under embargo, and Google Crawl Bot grabs it and makes it available.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mechanisms for triggering removal of this type of search result (where the content has already been removed or changed):

1. Submit an outdated content removal request through the form at: https://search.google.com/search-console/remove-outdated-content
   The documentation for this procedure is at: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7041154?hl=en
2. Ask the library to handle this through their Google Search Console account. This will work well if they have already gone through the steps to verify with Google their ownership of the domain that hosted the report. However, if they haven't done the verification, then it will basically be the same as if you submitted the request through your own account.

Comment: Thanks so much your reply and I really appreciate. Initially I filed a "Copyright Removal Request" to Google, and it didn't work out. And I studied what kind of situation should be filed to "Copyright removal," and I do feel my situation doesn't apply. Looks like your suggestion should be right. Thanks again.